# Best way to store a python Decimal object in MongoDB (using with Flask and Jinja)?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

So I'm creating an app that uses monetary data. I am using Flask for my app and storing data using Flask-pymongo (basically pymongo with some HTTP functionalities).

From my understanding - Flask doesn't have a Decimal object, so you have to cast the monetary value to Decimal128 (a BSON object).

Now, when I retrieve the value, I want to be able to manipulate it on the frontend (e.g. displaying totals), and the way I do it is this way:

data['data']['venue']['ATM']|string|float

As you can see, there is A LOT of casting going on. From Decimal -> Decimal 128 -> string -> float

Surely, I'm doing it in a very inefficient way and there has to be a better way. If there is, please let me know. Something about the multiple castings just feels wrong to me. If this way is totally okay - let me know as well

Thank you!

Comment: "As you can see, there is A LOT of casting going on. From Decimal -> Decimal 128 -> string -> float" I don't see the conversions. More than half of that are just dictionary keys.

Comment: @roganjosh Sorry for the confusion, the object being stored in Mongo is stored as data['data']['venue']['ATM']

Comment: So the process is:

Convert Decimal Value to Decimal128, store into mongodb.

Retrieve value from mongo, convert to str first because I can't convert straight from Decimal128 to float. So Decimal128 -> str -> float